# What was the name of 'Hindustan' before 'Bharat'?

Tags: name, india, terminology

Well I know that 'Hindustan' was called 'Bharat' after the name of king Bharat, but curious to know what was the ancient name prior to that?

Comment: Hindustan is not official name of our country. Hindustan word nowhere is being used in any of the govt. office or paper. On earlier time, our country had one name which is Bharat. Other 2 names are given by foreigners. British used to call our country as India and muslims used to call our country as Hindustan. Because of British rule, our country did officially accept India as name of the Country BUT Hindustan is never been officially accepted as our country's name. In every court or on every govt. paper who is in Hindi, there you will only see BHARAT written on it, not Hindustan.

Comment: @Rishabh that I know as well not using here in the question in that context. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 'Nabhivarsha' was the name of 'Hindustan' before 'Bharata'.

Comment: From where do we get more info about that name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name was **Ajanābha-varṣa**. This was the name given to the planet earth. But after the activities of the king Bharata, the country is named as Bhārata-varṣa.

This is said in the Śrīmad Bhāgavatam. [Skanda 5 chapter 7](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/7/3)

> ajanābhaṁ nāmaitad varṣaṁ bhāratam iti yata ārabhya vyapadiśanti.
>
> Formerly this planet was known as Ajanābha-varṣa, but since Mahārāja Bharata’s reign it has become known as Bhārata-varṣa.

This country was named after King Nābhi. He is the grandfather of King Bharata. After the reign of Bharata, son of Ṛṣabhadeva,  it is being called as Bhārata-varṣa.

Comment: thanx for the answer but I found more info about this name out here as well http://decodehindumythology.blogspot.ca/2012/01/india-and-bharat.html, worth reading. Some really interesting facts there.

Comment: That's a helpful link. The article gave verses from Vishnu Purana whereas I gave from Bhagavata Purana.

Comment: @Just_Do_It Yes, that's a helpful article. Credits to [Dr.Vineet Aggarwal](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/10481/dr-vineet-aggarwal).